# fetch upcommited changes after checkout

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

is there any way to fetch uncommited changes I left when I checkout out a new branch (dumb, I know!!)

I switched back the branch I was on, and I still have the following message, leading me to believe they might be somewhere I can get to!

```
    M   app-switcher.tmproj
    M   as_user_check.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch from one branch to another, and the change of branches wouldn't affect files that you've modified in your working tree, your working copy of those files won't be affected.  The output that you see from `git checkout` is reminding you of that.

To see the unstaged changes in those files, you can just do:

```
git diff
```

... and you can just checkout the branch you want to commit those changes to and `git add` and `git commit` as usual.

One possible source of confusion is that you'll see the same output (with an `M` prefix) if the changes have been staged.  In that case, to see the changes, you'll have to do:

```
git diff --cached
```

In that case, you can just switch to the right branch with `git checkout` and commit those changes with `git commit`.  If you want to unstage the changes, you can do:

```
git reset HEAD -- as_user_check.php
```

... as the output of `git status` should prompt you.